# Video.js PlayToggle event conflict

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

**Objective:** bind spacebar key to play/pause video embedded via video.js

**Problem:** while quite straightforward at first glance, it seems like the click event on the playtoggle button @ controlbar messes up the event (might be some kind of race condition problem). The `<video>` tag is being inserted via jQuery < jHXR request.

**Description**: Here is the code:

```
var
    self = this,
    vSrc = 'blah/Blah',
    videoOptions = {
        controlBar: {
            children: {
                volumeControl: false,
                muteToggle: false,
                fullscreenToggle: false
            }
        },
        poster: app.profile.virtualPath + '/Content/images/General/logo-web.png'
    };

var vC = $('<div class="video-container" />');
var vTag = $('<video controls preload="none" id="v1" width="100%" height="auto">' +
    '<source src="' + vSrc + '" type="video/mp4" />' +
    '</video>');

vC.append(vTag);
$(this.element).prepend(vC);

this.videoPlayer = videojs("v1", videoOptions, function () {
    this.one('play', function (e) {
        this.posterImage.hide();
    });
});

$(document).on('keyup.video', function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        self.videoPlayer.controlBar.playToggle.trigger('click');
    }
});
```

It works alright if I use only keyboard to start (no autoplay is required), play and pause video. It even works alright if I click the video itself (starts playing), hit space (it pauses), click video/hit spacebar again (it continues playing). *However* as soon as the PlayToggle button is clicked to play the video, hitting the spacebar will only pause the video for a blink of an eye (not even a second) and resume playing. Again, the spacebar mouseup event just triggers "click" event on a playtoggle button, nothing else!

Any ideas what's happening here?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** Surprisingly, when a control component @controlBar is clicked, it stays focused. Apparently this behavior was causing the error. The following line has solved the problem, but hey... tell me why this should be the default behavior?

```
$(this.videoPlayer.controlBar.el()).find('.vjs-control').on('click', function (e) {
     $(this).trigger('blur');
});
```